# Configure windows firewall for pinging and RDP

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, windows-firewall

2 Windows 7 desktop A and B at home network.

A's firewall on, A ping B = OK, B ping A = Request timed out.

A's firewall off,A ping B = OK, B ping A=OK.

What I need to configure for A's firewall.I do not want to turn off the windows firewall.

Comment: You need to add an exception for ICMP requests, see this question
http://serverfault.com/questions/106424/server-wont-respond-to-ping

Comment: I actually can not rdp to it either , how can enable that from windows firewall.I have alraedy enabled remote access from computer properties.

Comment: open port 3389 in your windows firewall for remote desktop

Answer (score 0):

To add a rule allowing inbound RDP traffic in the Windows 7 firewall, perform the following steps: 
1) Open the control panel and go to the Windows Firewall. 
2) On the left, click Advanced Settings. 
3) Go to the Inbound Rules on the left and scroll down until you find Remote Desktop (TCP-in). Double-click the rule to modify it 
4) You can choose to allow the connection or allow if secure (requires IPSec) but either way the rule must be enabled. 
5) If you want to restrict to a specific source IP, go to the Computers tab, check the box that says Only allow connections from these computes then Add the IP of the workstation you want to connect from (You'll need to make sure this is a static IP or DHCP reservation). 
To add the rule allowing you to ping the workstation, do the follwoing:
1) Open the control panel and go to the Windows Firewall. 
2) On the left, click Advanced Settings. 
3) Right-click Inbound Rules and choose New Rule 
4) Choose Custom 
5) Leave All Programs selected - choose Next 
6) Under protocol type choose ICMPv4 or ICMPv6 depending on how you're pinging. If you aren't sure choose ICMPv4. 
7) Choose Customize, Specific ICMP Types and check the box "Echo Request"
8) Select which local IP's addresses to which the rule should apply. If unsure leave it on all. 
9) If you only want to allow a single other workstation to ping this workstation, enter the other workstation's IP in the "remote" section on this screen then click next
10) Choose to allow the connection or allow it secure (requires IPSec)
11) next next finish.

Comment: +1 but there should already be a rule for `Networking(ICMP Echo Request)` or something similar. I don't remember the exact name.